# Is there any way to programmatically set AVS & CV2 checks on / off?

Tags: c#, opayo

We're looking to upgrade Sage Pay from v2.22 to v3.0. As part of this we also want to switch on AVS & CV2 checks. However, we have multiple work streams all connecting to the same Sage Pay test environment, which means if we turned it on for our work stream it would break a whole load of tests for other work streams. Is there any way to turn this on programmatically so it could be done only for the v3 stuff?

Alternatively is there a way of doing that through MySagePay? From what I can see [here](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/address-postcode-and-security-key-checks) it's simply an on / off (with various levels of compliance) and not by version, but perhaps there's something I've not seen.

Comment: Why -1? Please explain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn it on/off on a by transaction basis, if that helps. From the protocol doc:

Using this flag you can fine tune the AVS/CV2 checks and rule set you’ve defined at a transaction level. This is useful in circumstances where direct and trusted customer contact has been established and you wish to override the default security checks.

0 = If AVS/CV2 enabled then check them. If rules apply, use rules (default)

1 = Force AVS/CV2 checks even if not enabled for the account. If rules apply, use rules.

2 = Force NO AVS/CV2 checks even if enabled on account.

3 = Force AVS/CV2 checks even if not enabled for the account but DON’T apply any rules.